# Bit shifting with hex in Python

Tags: c#, python

I am trying to understand how to perform bit shift operations in Python. Coming from C#, it doesn't work in the same way.

The C# code is;

```
var plain=0xabcdef0000000; // plaintext
var key=0xf0f0f0f0f123456; // encryption key

var L = plain;
var R = plain>>32;
```

The output is;

```
000abcdef0000000 00000000000abcde
```

What is the equivilent in Python? I have tried;

```
plain = 0xabcdef0000000
key = 0xf0f0f0f0f123456

print plain

left  = plain
right = plain >> 32

print hex(left)
print hex(right)
```

However, it doesn't work. The output is different in Python. The 0's padding are missing. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: what exactly means "it doesn't work"?

Comment: I didn't get the same output with the Python version. The padded 0's are missing.

Comment: but you know that `0x00000000000abcde == 0xabcde`, right? Anyway, for printing, `string formatting` will do the trick.

Comment: Yes, but `0xabcdef != 0xabcde`

Comment: @TomSothcott: where in your C# code do you see `0x0000000000abcdef` then? Shifting `0xabcdef0000000` 32 bits to the right still resulted in `0x00000000abcde` being printed, because that's the 64-bit value produced. The last 8 bits were *shifted off*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `hex()` function does not pad numbers with leading zeros, because Python integers are *unbounded*. C# integers have a fixed size (64 bits in this case), so have an upper bound and can therefor be padded out. This doesn't mean those extra padding zeros carry any meaning; the integer value *is the same*.

You'll have to explicitly add those zeros, using the `format()` function to produce the output:

```
print format(left, '#018x')
print format(right, '#018x')
```

The `#` tells `format()` to include the `0x` prefix, and the leading `0` before the field width asks `format()` to pad the output:

```
>>> print format(left, '#018x')
0x000abcdef0000000
>>> print format(right, '#018x')
0x0000000000abcde
```

Note that the width includes the `0x` prefix; there are 16 hex digits in that output, representing 64 bits of data.

If you wanted to use a dynamic width based on the number of characters used in `key`, then calculate that from [`int.bit_length()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length); every 4 bits produce a hex character:

```
format(right, '#0{}x'.format((key.bit_length() + 3) // 4 + 2))
```

Demo:

```
>>> (key.bit_length() + 3) // 4 + 2
17
>>> print format(right, '#0{}x'.format((key.bit_length() + 3) // 4 + 2))
0x0000000000abcde
```

But note that even the key is only 60 bits in length and C# would pad that value with an `0` as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have no problem with you you tried

```
>>> hex(0xabcdef0000000)
'0xabcdef0000000'

>>> hex(0xabcdef0000000 >> 32)
'0xabcde'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [83]: plain=0xabcdef0000000    

In [84]: plain>>32
Out[84]: 703710

In [85]: plain
Out[85]: 3022415462400000

In [87]: hex(plain)
Out[87]: '0xabcdef0000000'
```

if

```
In [134]: left  = plain
In [135]: right = plain >> 32
```

Then

```
In [140]: '{:0x}'.format(left)
Out[140]: 'abcdef0000000'

In [143]: '{:018x}'.format(right)
Out[143]: '0000000000000abcde'
```